# GCM: NotRegistered and MissingRegistration?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I get response from the GCM server that has some errors.

something like: `NotRegistered` and `MissingRegistration`

What do these two errors indicate ? Shall I delete their regID ?

Comment: Check with new sender id and api key

Comment: Try to check it on mobile data, sometime WIFI not working and also make new server key for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two different errors.

`NotRegistered` means that the registration ID for which you got this error is not registered to GCM anymore. It's possible the corresponding app was uninstalled from the device.

`MissingRegistration` means that you failed to pass a registration ID in a request to GCM server, which indicates a problem in your server code.